# how to prevent a div leaving out of screen?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to do something like the "How to Format" on Ask Question page of stackoverflow.

Originally the `div` has `position:relative`. When any part of the `div` is out of screen, it becomes `position:fixed`.

How to implement it?

Edit: More precisely, what I want is:

At beginning, the `div` is Xpx from the top of window.
When I scroll down (X+Y)px, normally, the top Ypx part of the `div` will be hidden.
But I hope the whole `div` be fixed on the top of window. i.e. {position:fixed;top:0}
And if I scroll up back, the `div` will go back to Xpx from the top of window.

More more precisely, I want a more beautiful code for this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var e = $('#myDiv');
    var offsetTop = e.offset().top;
    var positionTop = e.position().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > offsetTop) {
            e.css({'position' : 'fixed', 'top' : '0px'});
        }
        else {
            e.css({'position': 'relative', 'top': positionTop});
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see anything inelegant with that code, other than the fact you may want to concatenate the two `e.css`'s together in the `else` block, remove the needless `event` argument and fix up part of the formatting. **EDIT**: I'll post an answer with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var e = $('#myDiv');
    var jWindow = $(window);
    var offsetTop = e.offset().top;
    var positionTop = e.position().top;

    jWindow.scroll(function()
    {
        if(jWindow.scrollTop() > offsetTop)
            e.css({'position':'fixed', 'top':0});
        else
            e.css({'position':'relative', 'top':positionTop});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a piece of code which really works:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var e = $('#myDiv');
    var offsetTop = e.offset().top;
    var positionTop = e.position().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + 20 > offsetTop) {
                e.css({'position' : 'fixed', 'top' : '20px'});
        }
        else {
            e.css('position', 'relative');
            e.css('top', positionTop);
        } 
    });
});
```

But I wonder whether there is a better solution.

Comment: The OP did not specify anything about position (`top`) requirements.

Comment: It's just for smooth animation.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted @lai-yu-hsuan 's code above and it didn't work.  The sticky element would disappear after the initial scroll if you scrolled back up, but this worked as intended for me.  I hope this helps someone!  Please note that I changed the sticky element to a class, "sticky-top" so it can apply to multple containers.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    var e = jQuery('.sticky-top');
    var offsetTop = e.offset().top;
    var positionTop = e.position().top;
    var positionLeft = e.position().left;
    var stickyWidth=e.width();
    var stickyHeight=e.height();

    jQuery(window).scroll(function(event) {
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() + 20 > offsetTop) {
                e.css({'position' : 'fixed', 'top' : '20px','left':positionLeft+'px'});
                e.css({'width':stickyWidth+'px','height':stickyHeight+'px'});
        }
        else {
                   e.css('position', 'relative');
                   e.css('top', '');
                   e.css('left','');
        } 
    });
});
```